# Custom theme JavaScript not executing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm attempting to translate a static page into a WP theme. I've enqueued all scripts like this (on functions.php):

```
      function brighterweb_scripts(){
    /* add styles*/
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-core', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('full-page', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fullPage/jquery.fullPage.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('full-page-example', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fullPage/examples.css');



    /*add scripts*/
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'), true, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), true, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-slim-scroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fullPage/vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js', array('jquery'), true, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('fullpage', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fullPage/jquery.fullPage.js', array('jquery'), true, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('fullpage-example', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fullPage/examples.js', array('jquery'), true, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('responsive-menu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/menu.js', array('jquery'), true, true);
  }
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'brighterweb_scripts');
```

Css works fine but when I check the page's source code, all JavaScript files are there but they don't work on the website (they work fine on the static/non-wordpress page). Live sample is here:

http://brighterwebdesign.co.uk/wp-theme/ -> wordpress theme

Any idea why the JavaScript is not doing anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the console you will see several issues. I only see one 404 on a js file.  It looks like you may be neglecting to load jquery on your site because I see references to '$' but they are coming back undefined.  You also have a lot of broken images.  Double check your link references and make sure jquery is loading before the rest of your jquery references.

[console log of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkHld.png)